# EPUB to PDF conversion using calibre giving error

Tags: php, linux, cakephp-1.3, calibre

Below is the error that I am getting while I use the code

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/ebook-convert test.epub mech4eck.pdf");
<br>echo $output;
```

I need to run this with PHP only, and so I am trying to execute the shell commands. I am using Ubuntu 12.

> No write acces to /root/.config/calibre using a temporary dir instead /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6) /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version`GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6) 1% Converting input to HTML... InputFormatPlugin: EPUB Input running on /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.epub Found HTML cover content/calibre_title_page.html Parsing all content... 34% Running transforms on ebook... Merging user specified metadata... Detecting structure... Flattening CSS and remapping font sizes... Source base font size is 12.00000pt Removing fake margins... Cleaning up manifest... Trimming unused files from manifest... Creating PDF Output... 67% Creating PDF Output

Answer (score 0):

I know none out here helped but I figured out on it my own.

Here is the trick

```
Rename the file /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 to /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1.bak

Taddda it works :)
```